# Magento contact form customizations

Tags: magento, customization

I'm trying to add a couple fields to the contact form so that my customers can indicate the year make and model of their vehicle when writing.

I have just upgraded my Magento installation from 1.4.3 to 1.7.0.1. My previous contact form was a hack job and this time I'm trying to get it working the right way. Reading all around, I tried adding `<input type="text" size="15" value="" id="model_ext" name="bike_model_ext" class="required-entry input-text">` to the form.phtml in my template and then in the transaction email template in admin, `{{var data.model_ext}}`. But that doesn't work. I ensured that the template in the back end is correct by manipulating the text. I also know the form.phtml is correct, as I see elements when they change.

So then I overloaded the controller handling the contact form. I confirmed my controller is handling it (it came with a `echo "it works"; die();`) And in there, I'm looking for the POST data of the extra form element names, but here, too, I'm having troubles getting access to the data. Looking around the net, I tried this:

```
            $comment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('comment');
            $extras=Array( "year","make","model","model_ext" );
            foreach($extras as $field)
                    $comment .= "\n$field:\t".$this->getRequest()->getPost($field);
            $this->getRequest()->setParam('comment', $comment);
            parent::postAction();
```

But again, it is like my variables do not exist. Here, again, I know my code is being executed, because when I get anything wrong in there, the contact form crashes to an error message.

I'll be on it again in the morning, but hope that there is something easy I'm missing that someone here with more experience can help me with.

**EDIT: ANSWERED** I was using the ID to key in for the variables, needs to instead be the name.

Comment: In the post it uses the name not the id:  name="bike_model_ext" take that in consideration

Comment: Yes! Thank you. That was the fix. Answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer for those interested by this fix.

The $_POST and $_GET value generated by a form use name and not id.

In this situation you have to use bike_model_ext instead of model_ext.

Kind Regards,